# MySQL Inner Join changes the order of records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table **Table1** which has 5 columns like this

```
|   ID   |   Name  |   V1   |   V2   |   V3   |
|   1    |    A    |   103  |   507  |   603  |
|   2    |    B    |   514  |   415  |   117  |
```

and another table **Table2** which has values like this

```
|  Values |  Rooms  |
|   103   |   ABC   |
|   507   |   DEF   |
|   603   |   GHI   |
|   514   |   JKL   |
|   415   |   MNO   |
|   117   |   PQR   |
```

I am running a join query to get rooms from **Table2** joined by **Table1** as

```
SELECT t2.values, t2.rooms, t1.Name FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.V1 = t2.Values
                    OR t1.V2 = t2.Values
                    OR t1.V3 = t2.Values;
```

this query gets the result but in ascending order of t2.values. I do not want to change any order. I just want to get result in whatever the **Table1** has values.

```
|  Values |  Rooms  |  Names  |
|   103   |   ABC   |    A    |
|   117   |   PQR   |    B    |
|   415   |   MNO   |    B    |
|   507   |   DEF   |    A    |
|   514   |   JKL   |    B    |
|   603   |   GHI   |    A    |
```

The above result is ordered according to T2.Values and these values come form t1.V1, t1.V2, T1.V3. I do not want the order result. I want the result to be according the t1.V1, t1.V2, T1.V3 values. If we see at **Table1** the values would be 103, 507, 603, 514, 415, 117 and therefore the result should be

```
|  Values |  Rooms  |  Names  |
|   103   |   ABC   |    A    |
|   507   |   DEF   |    A    |
|   603   |   GHI   |    A    |
|   415   |   MNO   |    B    |
|   514   |   JKL   |    B    |
|   117   |   PQR   |    B    |
```

I hope I made my explaination somehow better. Please If it still doesnt clear let me allow to edit it more.

As **paxdiablo** suggested, I tried adding ORDER BY t1.name but that is not sorting and result is same. Why?

Comment: That's how it works. If you want a specific order, always use an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @jarlh What if I don't want any specific order? Any way out there?

Comment: Easy, just skip the ORDER BY...

Comment: I searched google but could not find skipping **order by** because I am already not using any ORDER BY

Comment: You say you don't want a specific order, but then you complain about the order... You have to decide if the order matters or not. If it doesn't matter, don't care. If it matters, add an ORDER BY to both queries!

Comment: @jarlh I am sure that I do not want any order.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow Then your result is fine, it is, indeed, unordered.

Comment: I think we may be misunderstanding what you want. If you don't specify an ORDER BY, a SQL statement will return rows in an entirely arbitrary order, which may change over time. If you specify an ORDER BY, rows will be sorted in that order. There's no middle ground here. Is it possible that you *do* actually want an order, but haven't managed to define it properly in your question? Can you describe in more detail exactly what you mean by "I just want to get result in whatever the Table1 has values"? Do you just want `ORDER BY t2.Values`?

Comment: If you do not want any specific order, stop complaining!!!

Comment: @Abdul, I think we're having a communication problem :-) If you are sure you do not want any order, why do you care about the fact the query is re-ordering? Either it matters or it doesn't. If it doesn't you have no problem. If it does, explicitly order and you have a solution.

Comment: @Abdul, *perhaps* you mean you don't want to impose your own order with an ordering clause. That's fine but you need to realise then that the rows can be returned in *any* order, even a different order based on database version, schema and even the data within the table that changes over time.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for your kind comments. Let me defined my problem clearly once again. Let me edit my question.

Comment: @paxdiablo please see my updates.

Comment: Do you actually have your new expected results in the order you want? Because you say "103, 507, 603, 514, 415, 117", but in your example output 415 comes before 514...

Comment: Abdul, think I understand better now, you want to sort on name, then on column position within the row. I've added an option to my answer to cover this and it appears MattG also has a solution. Hopefully, either of those will do  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but it looks to me like you want them sorted by the order of ID in table1, and then order of the column (v1, v2, v3) that you've matched on. In which case, something like this should work:

```
SELECT t2.`values`, t2.rooms, t1.Name FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.V1 = t2.`values`
                    OR t1.V2 = t2.`values`
                    OR t1.V3 = t2.`values`
ORDER BY
    t1.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.v1 = t2.`values` THEN 1
        WHEN t1.v2 = t2.`values` THEN 2
        WHEN t1.V3 = t2.`values` THEN 3
    END
```

(Note I'm quoting `values` because it's a keyword in SQL...)

What I'm doing here is:

First, I'm ordering by t1.id, which gets you the rough sort order based on the rows in the t1 tables.

Then I'm adding a secondary sort based on which `Values` column was matched in the result row, using a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement. For each row of your query results, if the result was produced by a match between `t1.v1` and `t2.values`, then the CASE statement evaluates to 1. If the result was because of a match between `t1.v2` and `t2.values`, then we get 2. If the result was because of a match between `t1.v3` and `t2.values`, then we get 3.

So the overall sort order is based first on the order of the rows in `t1`, and then within that on the order of which column got matched between `t1` and `t2` for each row in your results, which seems to be the requirement (though it's hard to put into words!)

Comment: WONDERFUL! Matt you gave the exact answer what I was asking for. Actually paxdiablo's answer was not the one I asked for but it taught alot and solved the problem in other way. Please would you kindly give some light on ORDER BY and CASE function in it. Please explain what it is actually doing in CASE and it's purpose.

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to get result in whatever the Table1 has values.

This is where you've made your mistake. `Table1`, at least as far as SQL is concerned, doesn't *have* an order. Tables are unordered sets to which you *impose* order when extracting the data (if you wish).

SQL `select` statements make absolutely *no* guarantee on the order in which results are returned, unless you specifically use `order by` or `group by`. Even `select * from table1` can return the rows in whatever order the DBMS sees fit to give them to you.

If you want a specific ordering, you need to ask for it explicitly. For example, if you want them ordered by the room name, whack an `order by t1.name` at the end of your query. Though I'd probably go the whole hog and use a secondary sort order as well, with `order by t1.name, t2.rooms`.

Or, to sort on the values, add `order by t2.values`.

---

For example, punching this schema/data into [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/):

```
create table table1(
    id    integer,
    name  varchar(10),
    v1    integer,
    v2    integer,
    v3    integer);
insert into table1 (id,name,v1,v2,v3) values (1,'a',103,507,603);
insert into table1 (id,name,v1,v2,v3) values (2,'b',514,415,117);

create table table2 (
    val   integer,
    room  varchar(10));
insert into table2(val,room) values (103,'abc');
insert into table2(val,room) values (507,'def');
insert into table2(val,room) values (603,'ghi');
insert into table2(val,room) values (514,'jkl');
insert into table2(val,room) values (415,'mno');
insert into table2(val,room) values (117,'pqr');
```

and then executing:

```
select t2.val, t2.room, t1.name from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.v1 = t2.val
                     or t1.v2 = t2.val
                     or t1.v3 = t2.val
```

gives us an arbitrary ordering (it may *look* likes it's ordering by `rooms` within `name` but that's not guaranteed):

```
| val | room | name |
|-----|------|------|
| 103 |  abc |    a |
| 507 |  def |    a |
| 603 |  ghi |    a |
| 514 |  jkl |    b |
| 415 |  mno |    b |
| 117 |  pqr |    b |
```

When we change that to sort on two descending keys `order by t1.name desc, t2.room desc`, we can see it re-orders based on that:

```
| val | room | name |
|-----|------|------|
| 117 |  pqr |    b |
| 415 |  mno |    b |
| 514 |  jkl |    b |
| 603 |  ghi |    a |
| 507 |  def |    a |
| 103 |  abc |    a |
```

And, finally, changing the ordering clause to `order by t2.val asc`, we get it in value order:

```
| val | room | name |
|-----|------|------|
| 103 |  abc |    a |
| 117 |  pqr |    b |
| 415 |  mno |    b |
| 507 |  def |    a |
| 514 |  jkl |    b |
| 603 |  ghi |    a |
```

---

Finally, if your intent is to order it by the order of columns in each row of `table1` (so the order is left to right `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, you can introduce an artificial sort key, either by using a `case` statement to select based on which column matched, or by running multiple queries which may be more efficient since:

- you're not executing per-row functions, which tend not to scale very well; and
- in larger DBMS', they can be parallelised.

The multiple query option would go something like:

```
select 1 as minor, t2.val as val, t2.room as room, t1.name as name from table2 t2
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.v1 = t2.val
union all select 2 as minor, t2.val as val, t2.room as room, t1.name as name from table2 t2
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.v2 = t2.val
union all select 3 as minor, t2.val as val, t2.room as room, t1.name as name from table2 t2
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.v3 = t2.val
order by name, minor
```

and generates:

```
| minor | val | room | name |
|-------|-----|------|------|
|     1 | 103 |  abc |    a |
|     2 | 507 |  def |    a |
|     3 | 603 |  ghi |    a |
|     1 | 514 |  jkl |    b |
|     2 | 415 |  mno |    b |
|     3 | 117 |  pqr |    b |
```

You can see there that it uses `name` as the primary key and the position of the value in the row as the minor key.

Now some people may think it an ugly approach to introduce a fake column for sorting but it's a tried and tested method for increasing performance. However, you shouldn't trust me (or anyone) on that. My primary mantra for optimisation is *measure, don't guess.*

Comment: So do you have any idea how can I achieve the result in which my column ordering is not disturbed? I don't care if any other column is ordered. I just do not want the order or Values be changed.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow Why not `ORDER BY Rooms` ? Unless the provided values are dummy ones, of course. In this case, you'll have to add an ordering value to your table2.

Comment: Nup Needs the result be ordered according to column values of V1, V2 and V3.

Comment: If you want to have a defined order, do something like adding an AUTO_INCREMENT field on the table. If you then order by that, the rows will always come back in the order you inserted them.

Comment: As you suggested, I see one way out, I tried ORDER BY t1.name but that doesnt work and do not sort by name. Why?

Comment: @Abdul, not sure how you've done it but I tried it in SQLFiddle with success. Have posted extra information showing the tests, hopefully that will help you out.

Comment: @paxdiablo I made my solution through your ideas and was working well but please see Matt's answer it is just exactly the same I was talking about. Thank alot for your kind kind efforts to explain with SQL Fiddle. I learnt alot from you. Thanks again

Comment: No probs, Matt's answer is as good as what I added to the bottom of my answer, and it's not like I *need* the rep :-) Good luck.

Comment: You already got the World Bank of Reputation :). Thank Paxdiablo

Comment: And you got a +1 from me for drawing out the real question, too :)

Answer (score 0):

well the query is sorting the table using Values in ascending order - like "103 < 117 < 415 and so on..." but you want them to take the order in which they are sorted in actual table i.e. "103 than 507 than 603 and so on" which is sorted the way they have been inserted and you just want to retain this order of sorting.. one possible way you can achieve that is using an extra timestamp field in second table that can track the time insertion is done and thus you can use that timestamp like " ORDER BY timestamp " in your query..